# Create Unpivoted Structure from JSON Dictionary Pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON dataset `thing.json` that looks like this:

```
{
  "date" : "2021-04-01",
  "id" : 123,
  "data" : {
    "field1" : "blah",
    "field2" : "blahblah",
    "field3" : "blahblahblah"
  }
}
```

Loading it into a dataframe looks like this:

```
df = spark.read.format("json").load("/mnt/container/thing.json")
```

| date | id | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 | 123 | {"field1":"blah","field2":"blahblah","field3":"blahblahblah"} |

I want to explode out the nested dataframe in the data column like this:

| date | id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 | 123 | field1 | blah |
| 2021-04-01 | 123 | field2 | blahblah |
| 2021-04-01 | 123 | field3 | blahblahblah |

How can I write this transformation in pyspark--*in a way that scales if the object really nested in the "data" column has thousands of keys*?

Comment: spark version ?

Comment: databricks 8.2 spark 3.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the struct to a map through a JSON and then explode the map:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.select(
    'date', 
    'id', 
    F.explode(F.from_json(F.to_json('data'), 'map<string,string>'))
)

df2.show()
+----------+---+------+------------+
|      date| id|   key|       value|
+----------+---+------+------------+
|2021-04-01|123|field1|        blah|
|2021-04-01|123|field2|    blahblah|
|2021-04-01|123|field3|blahblahblah|
+----------+---+------+------------+
```